# PHP scandir() Returns an Empty Array on Network Folder

Tags: php, apache, scandir

I am running `scandir($path)` where `$path` is a network location and it is behaving in a very strange manor. In my script, I have path as

```
$path = "\\\\server-name\\shared folder"
$folders = scandir($path)
```

When I do a `var_dump($folders)` I get `array(0) {}`

When this happens, I restart the `Apache 2.4` service and if I run the script again after restarting the service, I get the anticipated result. When the command `scandir()` fails, I can't get any records in the `error.log` file of apache folder in XAMPP.

Could somebody explain why it works when the `Apache` service is restarted and why it stops working again after a while please?

Additional Info: 
Server - Windows Server 2008 R2 / PHP Version - 5.5.11

Comment: Is the Apache service running as LocalSystem? Thinking this might be a permission problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. `Apache` is logged in as a network user and it has the permission to reed or write to the folder. My problem is, why would it work for a while and then stop working? and why it start working again when the `Apache` service is restarted?